# What is the proper response to a "Range: bytes=0-" request for a live stream?

Tags: html, http, video-streaming

I am doing fragmented mp4 live streaming over http for a html5 video tag and so far it is happily working with Chrome, however FF and IE seem to be failing. VLC and ffplay also play the stream fine. I tried to look into more details that could make FF unhappy and eventually found that I was using the wrong HTTP respone code - I was sending `200 OK` instead of `206 Partial Content`. I'm still not sure if this is what's upsetting FF and IE but after reading through the RFC's and everything I came to a conclusion that I do not know how to specify a response header for the request header `Range: bytes=0-`. I have a live stream and I do not know the length so that should be set as `*` but if I reply with `Content-Range: bytes 0- /*` even Chrome immediately closes the connection, so I guess it is wrong. So what is the correct respone header?

Or should I just ignore the request header and give back a `200 OK`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yeah, I successfully built the HTML5 video streaming server, but I've already forgotten what was the correct action here, but I can look it up.